# Using match for multiple range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying using match function to search in 2 column but match only run in 1 column. Is there any way to using match with multiple column range?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(C2:D5&"", A1&""))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(C:D&"", A1&"")*ROW(A:A))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({MATCH(A1, C:C, 0), MATCH(A1, D:D, 0)})
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(IFERROR(1/(1/(REGEXMATCH(C:D&"", A1&"")*ROW(A:A)))),,9^9))*1)
```

[image]